# sql UTC date conversion

Tags: sql-server, datetime, utc

I need to format my dates in sql server to the following format.

2010-09-09T23:59:00+0000

Any ideas how to achieve date time format using an SQL query?

Comment: What SQL engine? MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, [...]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CONVERT` will get you most of the way:

```
DECLARE @d DATETIME
SET @d = GETDATE()
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), @d, 126)
```

The only thing this won't give you is the timezone (because neither `datetime` nor `datetime2` hold any timezone information). You'll need to append this manuall - if you need any other timezone other than UTC, then you'll need to store this in a separate field in your schema. See [the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) for more on CONVERT.

Answer (score 0):

You may use CONVERT operator. For example:

```
convert(datetime, '2010-09-09', 127)
```

Third parameter is style. You may find appropriate style here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx